# How to install clang-14 ,clang++14 and related llvm toolsets in centos8

Tags: clang, llvm, centos8

I want to install clang-14 and clang++-14 in centos8 for x86-64 platform from repo. Did anyone have some idea about this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.